# How to use file and .assets files in a unity project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the assets/data of another game. All its assets are either in file or .assets type files. Apart from that there is only code in dll files. Is there a way to remake the game using it's file/.asset files?

Comment: add what you have done so far

Comment: Sounds slightly illegal

Comment: I've tried dragging the files into my own unity project. The game has a lot of obfuscated code so I want to remake the game using my own code.

Comment: you should also replaace the assets with your own assets

Answer (score 0):

If files are in a DLL and cant be decompiled into readable assembly code, the code was probably meant to be kept away from prying eyes. The same applies to .asset files, these files are encrypted, you will only decrypt them with a key that the owner of these files holds, if you're determined you could search for the key that makes these files readable from the original source, but it's not advised you try this and may be illegal, check the usability of these assets and Dll's. If it's legal to use these, you could try to decode the DLL with http://unity3d.netobf.com/Unity3dObfuscatorSetup.exe. If the asset files are not encrypted you could rename .assets to .asset and then in Unity just import new asset to access all of the models, textures, etc. Not all assets are obtainable but most of them are. This information came from this [unity thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/10879/is-it-possible-to-hackdecode-asset-files.html)